# Thumbprint for a signing certificate

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, certificate, signing

I need to extract Thumbprints of few binaries' certificates.
In PowerShell Get-AuthenticodeSignature can be used to get thumbprint value from binary, but if that file is Dual signed then also it shows only one thumbprint.
Is there any Powershell/ .NET utility to check multi thumbprints?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/reading-multiple-signatures-from-signed-file-with-powershell.aspx). This is the complex analysis of why only one certificate is returned and how to get the other ones.

Comment: Hi Robdy, thanks for your reply I have checked that link and it works. But I am looking for some tool from MS or Powershell which can directly help me.

Comment: @AbbyJangir `crypt32.dll` *is* a tool from MS.

Comment: I have looked at sigcheck and sign tool also but either they are not giving any thumbprint as output. So is there any tool like them which extracts all the thumbprints or I'll have to by crypt42.dll only.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [brilliant article](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/reading-multiple-signatures-from-signed-file-with-powershell.aspx) about why it's not possible by default and what's the workaround for that.

#### TL;DR:

Microsoft authenticode signature supports only one signature at a time. Additional signatures are done as nested signatures. First certificate can be easily accessed by using [`Get-AuthenticodeSignature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-authenticodesignature?view=powershell-6) and acessing `SignerCertificate` property. You have to use CryptoAPI to access additional certificates.

Once you follow the steps from the linked article you can simply run the following to get the information you need:

```
PS C:\> $sig = Get-AuthenticodeSignatureEx "C:\path\to\file.dll"
PS C:\> $sig | fl *
```

Comment: No worries - I know that it might be not suitable for your needs but just decided to put it as an answer so others might use it. From what I know it's the only way to do that currently. And for the future - you might want to be more specific in what kind of solution you are looking for as it's really not clear to me in that question - you asked about PowerShell solution and you were given a script with step by step explanation. Hope you're aware that you'll most likely have to use `.dll` files frequently unless you want to do very-low-level programming.